# Implementing Ehcache with Spring in GoogleAppEngine

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, google-app-engine, ehcache

I am migrating one of my spring project which contains the ehcaching  to GoogleAppEngine, 
But I am getting below exception :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.config.internalCacheAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.AnnotationCacheOperationSource#0' while setting bean property 'cacheOperationSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.AnnotationCacheOperationSource#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.config.internalJCacheAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.cache.jcache.interceptor.DefaultJCacheOperationSource#0' while setting bean property 'cacheOperationSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.jcache.interceptor.DefaultJCacheOperationSource#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in class path resource [root-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ehcache' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ehcache' defined in class path resource [root-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:87)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:347)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
... 38 more
```

Here are my config files:

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

ehcache.xml

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd">
<cacheManagerEventListenerFactory class="" properties="" />
<defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="10000"
   eternal="false"
   overflowToDisk="false"
   diskPersistent="false"
   timeToIdleSeconds="120"
   timeToLiveSeconds="120"
   memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU">
</defaultCache>
<!--Example sample cache -->
<cache name="sampleCache1" 
   overflowToDisk="false"
   diskPersistent="false"
   maxElementsInMemory="100" 
   eternal="false"
   timeToLiveSeconds="86400" 
   memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" /> </ehcache>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.xyz.*" />
<annotation-driven />
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<beans:import resource="classpath:root-context.xml" />
```

root-context.xml

```
<cache:annotation-driven cache-manager="cacheManager" />
<beans:import resource="classpath:ehcache.xml" />
<beans:bean id="cacheManager"
    class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
    <beans:property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcache" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="ehcache"
    class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml" />
</beans:bean>
```

I am using below versions :

- gae 1.9.46
- ehcahe 2.9.1
- spring 4.3.2.RELEASE

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the [latest documentation](http://www.ehcache.org/generated/2.10.3/html/ehc-all/#page/Ehcache_Documentation_Set%2Fco-gae_configuring_ehcache_xml.html%23), there are limitations when using Ehcache on Google App Engine.
GAE is a restricted environment where some APIs are not available.

You need to remove the `<cacheManagerEventListenerFactory class="" properties="" />` bit from your configuration.